# Instead of trigger is not updating my table

Tags: oracle, plsql, database-trigger

I have to check the new status on a table and, depending this status I need to update another table relationated with the first one.

Original table = origin_table

View = table_view

The View was created with a simple select:

```
create or replace view table_view as
select * from table
```

My trigger is basically:

```
create or replace trigger verify_status
    instead of update on table_view
    referencing old as old new as new
    for each row

begin

    if :new.status in ('A', 'P') then
        update origin_table set status = 'CP' where cod = :new.cod;
    end if;
end;
```

But my origin_table is not updating, some idea?

Obs: The view_table is a copy of a table with a relationship with the origin_table and not a view of a of the origin table.

ObsII: I had to do that to avoid the mutating table error.

Comment: Can you post your table and view definition, and how do you do the main update?

Comment: Did you ever COMMIT the changes? Until you execute a COMMIT statement you won't see the changes in the database.

Comment: Even adding a commit statement the update does not appear, stay the same...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any issue with your code, it works perfectly. Could you check dbfiddle link for more details,

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=8bad808cb6d120df37537044081e09b0

Comment: I follow the Oracle documentation to avoid mutating table error, and I don't see any errors too, but it does not update

Comment: Did you look at the DB fiddle link, it is updating the records by the way.

Comment: I update your model to my case, I think the table management is my problem, can you have a look at it please? https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=c11383614a1e4bfe35bb891c920f2eb0

Comment: You are updating timipr instead you have to update timipr2 which is your view. The trigger fires only when you update the view and not the table. update timipr2 set status = 'P' where iprimovel = 1;  check the link https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=8ee3dbe22041865da75e2b763976bad9

Comment: Is there a way to do it by updating timipr? Cause is a automatic update

Comment: In that case you don't need instead of trigger. Instead of trigger is used when view is formed by more than one table in general to update each of the tables. Check dbfiddle for changes - https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=8c29259d92aeffe18de762a0ddee49f2

Comment: There is the problem, I did it, but it accuses the mutation table error.

Comment: Did you check the dbfiddle link https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=4b8345fd52874db4442cb1fd60df9cd3. It doesn't throw mutating table error. Mutating table error is thrown when you are trying to modify a row within a trigger that is getting changed by the trigger itself and here your trigger is on timipr while your update is on timimv.

Comment: My problem was that two triggers was in conflict, by the purpose of my question, your answer was correct, thank you friend. Stay home :P